# Paging in PHP Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-3

I am trying to make a paging in Laravel, but i keep getting errors.

I try put

```
->paginate(3)
```

On the return, but i keep getting errors like Call to undefined method Laravel\Paginator::get() and Call to undefined method Laravel\Paginator::order_by()

```
public function get_index()
{
    $categories = Category::all();
    return View::make("stories.index")
        ->with("title","Sexnoveller")
        ->with("categories", $categories)
        ->with("stories", DB::table('stories')
        ->order_by('id', 'desc')->get());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use pagination call `paginate()` instead of `get()`. In your case that would be:

```
return View::make("stories.index")
       // ...
       ->with("stories", DB::table('stories')
       ->order_by('id', 'desc')->paginate(3));
```

Then in the view just remember to iterate over `$stories->results`.

Answer (score 1):

I do recommend to create a model for that Stories table. Once done, you could do something like:

```
Story::orderby('story_name', 'ASC')->paginate(10);
```